# Making a burglar alarm

Tags: temperature, ldr

I am using a passive infrared sensor TMP006 to make a burglar alarm. However I notice that the data returned is not accurate enough. Are there any other ways by which I can improve my accuracy. Or should I use an ldr on which I shine a continous beam of IR light which breaks when the burglar steps in?What do commercial burglar alarms use to detect motion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The TMP006 is a PIR, but a *temperature* sensor. This should be used in a situation where the temperature to be measured is equal over the full viewing angle. That would require the burglar to be very close to the sensor, something he might not want to. LDRs are no use either, they detect light levels.

The common way to detect a person's presence is a PIR *presence/motion* detector. I've used the Panasonic [NaPiOn](http://pewa.panasonic.com/assets/pcsd/catalog/napion-catalog.pdf) for this, which at the time was the smallest existing PIR.

[image]

It has a matrix of detection zones, which, combined with the multi-faceted lens will detect even slight movements at meters distance.

Use is easy. It has three pins: ground, Vcc, and output. The output goes high if the sensor detects a person moving in its detection field.

**Further reading:**
[NaPiOn design manual](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Electric%20Works%20PDFs/AMN%20Design%20Manual.pdf)

Comment: TMP006 is an pir. I have mentioned it in the question(https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=tmp006+passive+infra&oq=tmp006+passive+infra&gs_l=hp.3...813.9561.0.11089.20.20.0.0.0.0.353.4665.0j4j14j2.20.0...0.0...1c.IL9-tfPeFtA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9e68f70bf4c90d29&biw=1097&bih=465). I will definitely take a look at the panasonic NaPion. It seems interesting

Comment: @Sab - Correct, it's a PIR, but a temperature sensor, not a presence/motion detector.

Comment: Okay. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help. You said you have used NaPiOn. Did you interface it with a specific board?

Comment: @Sab - Thanks for the accept. I used it professionally, on a self-designed microcontroller board. I don't recall the microcontroller type, but that's not important; it will interface with about any microcontroller. Power it with the same voltage as the controller (it works on 3.3 V and 5 V), and connect the output to one of the controller's inputs. The design manual shows a pull-down resistor, but IIRC I didn't even use that.

Comment: Which website did you use to order the component since I am unable to find it in shops close to my place?

Comment: @Sab - we bought them through distribution, which is the normal way for production quantities. I mentioned the NaPiOn because it's listed on Digikey. But other brands/types may also be usable. Check voltage, that it's a digital output and detection range (sensitivity). I picked the NaPiOn at the time because it had to be small. So expect other type to be bigger, but that may not be a problem. Will probably be cheaper too.

Comment: Very nice- I was looking for something like this.. u can buy http://uk.mouser.com/panasonicnapion/

Comment: @ppumkin - thanks for the link. Like I said to *Sab* these aren't cheap, but I needed them for their small size. Other PIRs may be less expansive.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, LDR is not suitable for motion detection. I'm using **PIR Motion Detector,** works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Security system motion detectors use the detection mode of the combination of infrared and microwave, i.e. well-known dual technology. The microwave detection mode of the dual-technology detector is as follows: According to the Doppler Principle in physics, microwave sends at a frequency; when there is any moving object in its coverage range, microwave reflects at another frequency. Therefore, there is a frequency difference between the sending frequency and the reflection frequency. One's volume and moving speed can be gotten according to the detected variation. In combination with the infrared detected signals, the detector then performs operation processing of both triggering signals through the internal CPU chip, comprehensively analyzes relevant characteristics of the signals, and finally judges whether there is any invader in the visual area.

Comment: Specifically, the microwave sensor is sensitive to motion toward or away from the detector, while the PIR detector is sensitive to motion across the field of view. Together, you get detection of motion in any (horizontal) direction.